# Displaying events by date on a calendar from a db

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to build an events page for a local residents association.
I'm using laravel as my framework, but that's not so important to this question. I need to display a calendar of upcoming and past events. On the front end I am using bootstrap 3.

So far I've had no luck on finding a calendar to work with my requirements below:

1. Must be easily styled to match sites theme
2. Must be able to display a tooltip of the events data (which potentially includes a picture, a paragraph, and the time of the event) not a modal
3. Should be well documented, or at least have usable documents
4. Should still be supported if possible (not as important as 1-3)

Does anyone know of a calendar that matches these requirements?

Cheers, 
Peter McKinney

Comment: fullcalendar , within API can do everyhting mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Hope [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) jQuery Plugin will fulfill your needs